# KDEconnect not visible in KDE system settings

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 14.10, plasma

After installing kdeconnect on my fresh Ubuntu 14.10 and then installing whole plasma environment I am unable to see KDEconnect settings icon in KDE system settings.
On my previously Ubuntu installation I was somehow managed to create a desktop launcher and even see kdeconnect in installed app search. But now only I can do is to use kdeconnect indicator app.

Steps I made:

- Installed kdeconnect via Ubuntu Software Center
- compiled and installed kdeconnect indcator for ubuntu
- Installed KDE plasma environment via Ubuntu Software Center
- Logout and switch to (probably newest) plasma environment

I can't see nothing different in KDE settings that might look like phone or kdeconnect settings.

Please help me at least launch kdeconnect settings GUI.

Comment: I have found that under /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/ is a kdeconnectd app launcher which, as I remeber, have used when creating a desktop launcher. But when I try to launch it, it will response with that error:
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.

Comment: Somehow KDEconnect has appeared in apps to launch with kcmshell4 command when right-clicked. But now even launching indicator-kdeconnect runs with error above. Seems that I have to reinstall ubuntu again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to open a KDE Connect GUI settings is to enter a command

```
kcmshell4 kdeconnect
```

Also a KDE Connect launcher seems to be in

*/usr/share/applications/kde4*

with a commandline inside

```
kcmshell4 kcm_kdeconnect
```

Comment: But still to pair a device I have to install kubuntu-desktop :<

Ubuntu notification bubble has no Yes/No buttons and my phone has no pair confirmation but has a pair button instead